# Android: How to override few strings in same language

Tags: android, string, locale

I have folder for example 'values-ru/strings'.

How I can override few strings by setting it?

for example i have:

```
<str: "StringA":"first">
<str: "StringB":"second">
<str: "StringC":"third">
```

I need only if enabled my setting:

```
<str: "StringA":"zero">
<str: "StringB":"second">
<str: "StringC":"null">
```

Answer (score 1):

No way!, String files(String.xml) are kind of static, You can read but You can not modify at run time!. you may consider using string formater, If your requirement meets.

Comment: But what about set default "strings-ru", and use "strings-ru-upgraded" and if in "upgraded" not find strings, use default from "strings-ru"?